# Does inversion reverse order for positive elements in a unital C* algebra?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let's say that in a unital C* algebra, we have $b \geq a \geq 0$ and $a$ is invertible.  Then $b$ is also invertible.  Can we conclude that $a^{-1} \geq b^{-1}$?  If so, why?  Can any related statement be made if we only assume $a \leq b$? (And maybe that $a$, and hence $b$ are self adjoint.)

Comment: This is an abstract version of this earlier question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95862/positive-invertible-operators  (Essentially the same answer applies.  And it was applied by the same answerer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If $b \ge a \ge 0$ and $a$ is invertible, then $a^{-1/2} b a^{-1/2} \ge a^{-1/2} a a^{-1/2} = 1$
so $ a^{1/2} b^{-1} a^{1/2} = (a^{-1/2} b a^{-1/2})^{-1} \le 1$ and then $b^{-1} = a^{-1/2} a^{1/2} b^{-1} a^{1/2} a^{-1/2} \le a^{-1}$.
Without the $\ge 0$ it's false, e.g. try $a = -1$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: actually I saw that argument but I just don't understand why the special case you use in there holds.  You're saying that if $a \leq 1$ and $a$ is invertible, then $a^{-1} \geq 1$. (and vice versa)

Comment: Oh wait now I finally see.  The way to see this fact is to use the functional calculus, and compare $t$, $1/t$, and the constant function $1$ defined on the spectrum which is a compact subset of $(0, 1]$.

Comment: @Jeff: You can also show that directly, just using the spectrum, if you defined $b ≥ a$ by $\mathrm{spec}(b-a) \subseteq [0, ∞)$, which I believe is how it is commonly done for C*-algebras.