# Conway’s Functional Analysis, VIII §3 Exercise 11

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

This exercise is a step to proving inequalities involving non-commuting elements of a C*-algebra. (In particular in the subsequent exercise 12). Unfortunately I do not see, how to prove part (a):

For $α > 0, t ≥ 0$ define $$f_α(t) := \frac{t}{1 + αt} = \frac{1}{α}(1-\frac{1}{1+αt}),$$ then for any hermitian elements $a, b$ in a C*-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ with $0 ≤ a ≤ b$ we have that $$f_α(a) ≤ f_α(b).$$

For $a$ and $b$ commuting it is trivial, but how can it be done in the general case? Is there maybe a clever way to write $f_α(b) - f_α(a)$? The biggest obstacle is, that a product of positive elements does not have to be positive itself.

I hope that the argument can also be used for unbounded operators.

Comment: Try expand $f_\alpha$ into series and prove inequality for partial sums.

Comment: @Norbert: I do not see how that could work, as it is in general _not_ true, that $a^n ≤ b^n$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all of the work is in Exercise 8, which says that if $0\leq x\leq y$ in a C*-algebra and $x$ is invertible, then $y^{-1}\leq x^{-1}$.  You will apply this with $x=1+\alpha a$ and $y=1+\alpha b$, and the rest follows easily.

For a solution to Exercise 8, see [Does inversion reverse order for positive elements in a unital C* algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183486/inversion-in-a-unital-c-algebra)  or [For positive invertible operators $C\leq T$ on a Hilbert space, does it follow that $T^{-1}\leq C^{-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95862/) or [If $0\leq A\leq B$ on Hilbert space and $A^{-1}$ exists, show that $A^{-1}\geq B^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590215/inverse-of-positive-operators?lq=1) (soon to have better titles).

Comment: Thank you. This is one of the moments where something seems so obvious, once you have seen it.